# SSISDB package succeeds, but same package triggered as a job fails. ODBC password isn't carried into Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have a .dtsx that pulls data from a remote database via ODBC connection. The data is pulled, cleaned, and then placed in a local sql server table.

I deployed the package from SSIS via SSISDB and have it added as a step in a Server Agent job. When I execute the package from the Services Catalogs folder it succeeds but when I execute the job it fails. I know it's because the ODBC connection fails and I can see in the message that the connection string is being sent without a password.

Even when I look in the Connection Manager settings inside the Job setup menu I see the password as *****, but it isn't passed into the connection string when the caller is NT SERVICE\SQLAgent...

How can I remedy this?

Comment: Sounds like the package is configured to use Integrated Authentication, instead of password.  Try configuring the Agent job to run as the same user who triggered it in the SSIS catalog.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but in the Run As dropdown menu I am not given any options besides the SQL Agent... Is there a setting in the Logins menu that I need to toggle to add accounts to that menu?

Comment: Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver16